# Folder permissions batch update endpoint returns "access is denied" error

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to use the folder permissions bulk update endpoint
`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/docs/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/permissions:batch-update`
to update a role's permissions by passing in a body like this:

```
[
    {
        "subjectId": "<role id>",
        "subjectType": "ROLE",
        "actions": [
            "PUBLISH", "EDIT", "CONTROL", "VIEW", "DOWNLOAD", "COLLABORATE"
        ]
    }
]
```

The response I get is

```
{
    "code": "ERR_AUTHORIZATION_ERROR",
    "title": "The access is denied",
    "detail": "The access is denied on resource <my project id>"
}
```

I am using two-legged authentication and passing the id of an account admin user in the `x-user-id` header.

Comment: a few questions: 1. can it work with 3 legged token? 2, can it work with common user id? 3. can it work if adding the role in UI?  These may help to narrow down the issue

Answer (score 0):

So it seems not setting the `x-user-id` is the solution. When I removed it the request worked.